# Align image with top showing a portion of image in Swift 2 iOS 9

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, swift2, ios9.2

I need to align a `UIImageView` in a way that only top portion of the image is shown. (Please see the screenshot image, `UIImageView` is marked with red outline). 
Say the image has a width = 320px and height = 300px then I want to show full width:320px but for height only the top 100px should show up.

Please guide me how can i achieve the same on iOS 9 / Swift 2.0.

[image: play]

Answer (score 4):

You can use the contentMode property on your imageView to scale a part of the image. There are several different modes you can choose, in the example below I have used `UIViewContentMode.top`

```
let img = UIImage(named: "image")
imageView.contentMode = .top
imageView.clipsToBounds = true
imageView.image = img
```